# Unable to build Facebook SDK for iOS on Xcode8

Tags: ios, xcode8, fbsdk

I'm trying to add Facebook analytics for my first time but getting this error on Objective C project

> use of undeclared identifier 'applicationDidBecomeaAtive"[image]

My steps:
1- copy Bolts.framework and FBSDKCoreKit.framework

2- copy  to AppDelegate.m

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```

3- but the error in these lines

```
    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
        return YES;
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  myappgames
//
//  Created by Vishal on 9/10/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Vishal. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "UIDevice+Res.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>



@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize navigationObj;
@synthesize bannerViewAdUnitID,InterstitialAdUnitID;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    //--------Admob Ids---------
    bannerViewAdUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-00000";

    //--------InterstitialAd Ids---------
    InterstitialAdUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-00000000";


    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.viewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_IPad" bundle:nil];
        navigationObj = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewcontroller];
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationObj;
    } else {
        self.viewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        navigationObj = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewcontroller];
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationObj;
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}



- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}



    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}



- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Comment: would you please copy the full code again to test it

Comment: thanks, do you using AppDelegate.m or .h ?? it still giv me error , will attach the exact code to you

Comment: @heythem500  Copy Paste above code in your app delegate. First remove all old code in Appdelegate.m. Please appreciate my answer.

Comment: ok, got error "duplicate declartion" in the last lines for - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: I got many errors this time, but I get back to your edit before and deleted the duplicate line and it builds well what do you think?

Comment: Check New code. @heythem500 Now You appreciate. I am sorry last time I undo all your code.

Comment: @heythem500 Please appreciate my answer. Your appreciation make us to spend time on stackoverflow to help you.

Comment: @heythem500 please check my answer. I would be grateful to you. Thanks !

Comment: I did , you deserve that

Comment: how long does Facebook take time to show the activity? to make sure the stats works